# converting a video stream to an audio stream not working

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, azure-storage, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm extracting audio from a video using [ffmeg-fluent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) library

Actually when I save the audio in local it works. I get an audio file with data.

```
ffmpeg(recordedVideoStrm)
  .outputOptions([
    "-vn", // Discard the video
    "-acodec pcm_s16le", // Set the audio codec
    "-ar 44100", // Set the audio sample rate
    "-ac 2", // Set the number of audio channels
  ])
  .output("mp3")
  .on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
  })
  .on("end", function () {
    console.log("Audio extraction completed");
  })
  .save("output.wav");
```

But when I try to convert the video stream to audio stream in order to save the file in my azure blob storage I get an empty file with 0 octet size.

```
const audioStream = ffmpeg(recordedVideoStrm)
  .outputOptions([
    "-vn", // Discard the video
    "-acodec pcm_s16le", // Set the audio codec
    "-ar 44100", // Set the audio sample rate
    "-ac 2", // Set the number of audio channels
  ])
  .on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: " + err.message);
  })
  .on("end", function () {
    console.log("Audio extraction completed");
  })
  .pipe(); 

const stream = await blobClient.uploadStream(audioStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here I have a work around were, instead of using the `fluent-ffmpeg` to pipe the data in the stream  , we can store the audio to a file and read the file as stream and then upload it.
- here, I am writing the audio data to a `novideo.mp3`file and then uploading the file as a stream.

code:

```
var  writeStream = Stream.Writable();
ffmpeg({source:'newtest.mp4'})
    .noVideo()
    .saveToFile("novideo.mp4");
writeStream = fs.createReadStream('novideo.mp4');
await  blockblobclient.uploadStream(writeStream);
```

output:
[image]

- Also, if you want to use the `pipe()` function then I think you have to pass a writable stream to the function along with option . refer these [NPM- DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg#pipestream-options-pipe-the-output-to-a-writable-stream) for it

Comment: Thank you for the work around I think I will go for it for the moment, I'm using an azure function I do not prefer save files into it, but pipe data instead . Is there a way to save it as a temporary file , then the function delete it by itself ?

Comment: the `.saveToFile('novideo.mp4')` option will the create the file which we are uploading. we can delete this file again using: `fs.unlinkSync('novideo.mp4');`